# AS3 - How do you call previous currentTarget from within a different event?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I have a dropdown menu that lets you select an item to be placed on the stage.  The item is drag and droppable so I use `event.currentTarget.startDrag();` to start the drag.  Ok, everything works fine so far.

However, I also need to be able to rotate the item while it is being dragged (using the spacebar).

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
    function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        rotate++;
        if (rotate == 5){
            rotate = 1;

        }
        WHATGOESHERE?.gotoAndStop(rotate);
        }
```

If I hardcode in an instance name of an object everything works fine - so the rotate function is working properly.  The problem is, how can I reference event.currentTarget from the startDrag function while inside of the keyDown event?

My first thought was to set event.currentTarget to a variable and then calling the variable from within the keyDown event.  However, `targetHold = event.currentTarget;` does not seem to record the instance name of the object being clicked...

---

```
public var targetHold:Object = new Object;

function ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.currentTarget.startDrag();
    targetHold = event.currentTarget;
        trace ("targetHold " + targetHold);

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
    function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        rotate++;
        if (rotate == 5){
            rotate = 1;
        }
        targetHold.gotoAndStop(rotate); //does not work
        } 
    }


function ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    event.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you start and stop drag.  storing the `event.currentTarget` in a variable should work just fine.  Are you sure your `targetHold` var was defined globally and not inside a function?

Comment: this is just a guess, but what happens if you comment out the gotoAndStop? Does it still lose focus after the first rotate?

Comment: Interesting.  I added `trace ("rotate " + rotate);` to the beginning of the myKeyDown function.  With gotoAndStop in the code the response is 2 and then nothing else (it skips 1, goes to 2, and stops looping).  I commented out the gotoAndStop and the trace reports as exactly as it should - "1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do this:  (well, actually I'd follow @null's advice and encapsulate it in a sub class that all your dragable objects would extend, but that is a little broad so this will do)

```
public var targetHold:MovieClip; //don't make a new object, just create the empty var

public function YourConstructor(){
    //your other constructor code
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown); //don't add the listener in the click function
}

private function clickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(targetHold) ReleaseToDrop(null);  //safeguard in case flash lost the focus during the mouse up

    targetHold = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;  //assign the current target. Might as well cast it as MovieClip and get code completion benefits
    targetHold.startDrag();
    trace ("targetHold " + targetHold);
}

private function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    //check if target hold exists
    if (targetHold != null && e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        rotate++;
        if (rotate == 5){
            rotate = 1;
        }
        targetHold.gotoAndStop(rotate);
    } 
}

private function ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    if(targetHold) targetHold.stopDrag();
    targetHold = null;
}
```

Comment: I made the changes exactly as described - it still seems to lose focus when attempting to rotate.  Could I possibly impose on you (or @null) to provide a brief example of how to set this up using a class - I'm self teaching myself AS3/Flash and have yet to fully "get" OOP.

Comment: I just noticed you have a `public` keyword in your code.   Can you post the entire class file the code is from?  or at least the parts where you call clickToDrag and releaseToDrop.     The code I posted should work and it would be good to figure out what in your circumstance is making it loose focus.

Comment: Plus, what does your gotoAndStop(rotate) actually do on that frame?

Comment: It is connected to a MovieClip with 4 frames - it simply rotates through the 4 frames of the clip.

Comment: Finally got it using your code!  I had some {}s out of place was one problem.  The other, main problem, was that I had a textfield inside the rotating MovieClip.  I removed the textfield and now it works.  Now I just have to figure out how to make it work WITH the textfield. :D  Thanks so much for your help Batman and null!

Comment: If it's a matter of focus, you can set `mouseEnabled = false` on the text field.     WIthout seeing the .fla it's difficult to help further.

Answer (score 2):

As you click the object, it should have focus. If you register the listener for the `KeyboardEvent` on the object and not on the stage, it will be `.currentTarget`.

Here's an example of what I have in mind. Right after starting the drag, add the listener to the same object instead of the stage.

```
event.currentTarget.startDrag();
event.currentTarget.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
```

---

The proper way of doing this would be to define all the functionality in a class. Within a self contained class, you would not need any `.currentTarget`.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution I think,  you should add an example though

Comment: @jdfinch3 I added one for the quick solution. If you want an example for a class, you'd have to provide all the information on what's going on in your code.

Comment: Ok, it's semi working using `event.currentTarget.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);` - It does 1 rotation though, and then loses focus and has to be reclicked...